# Laravel 5 and AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, api, rest, laravel

I want to create a website using Laravel 5 for the back-end and Angular for the front.

I have some difficulties about how to proceed correctly :

***- How to handle multi-language ?***

in Laravel, all translations are in a file that is render to the view depending of the user chosen language. How to do with Angular when I am supposed to use the backend for RESTful request ?

***- How to deal with other part of the view ?***

I have a menu (of 2 of 3 levels deep). Do I have to send a request for the menu to the backend every time a page is loaded ? Or the server automatically send the menu with the demanded content ? ... I say menu but it can be other part of the view like the sidebar, ...

Comment: Not hard to research translations in angular, and there are numerous directives available. As for the menu I think you need to work with angular a bit more to realize you don't need to send request for each view change

Comment: Is there any (solution) link available?